# look up a value in excel and return count if cell above or below contains data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

I have looked at other posts with similar issues by think mine might either be unique or requires placeholders (or combining formulas).  An example of my spreadsheet is below.

I'm trying to get a count of all the yellow highlighted cells that has data when matching the name (Charlie, bravo, delta, etc.).  For example, in a table next to this one, Charlie would have a count of 2 and golf would have a count of 1 and all others would either be blank or zero.

Most other posts are utilizing index/match but they are only looking at 1 row.

[image: table of who has completed their task.]

Comment: Formulas cannot determine if the cell is colored or not.  Is you data always in three row bunches like above?

Comment: Not really concerned if the cell is colored or not, only if there is data in there.  To answer your second question, actually the data is in 10 row bunches.
I'm wondering if I'll have to use a sum with index/match for each row.

Comment: Nope, use countifs with offset ranges that are the same size.  see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$J$8,"golf",$A$3:$J$9,"<>")
```

Assumes your picture starts in A1 and that the pattern shown is consistent.

Comment: Thanks, a lot simpler than I thought it would be.